# Ruby FileUtils.mv with force flag is not working

Tags: ruby

I'm not a Ruby guy but I was assigned to modify our build script. The script is trying to move  (**rename**) a file but I'm not sure why I'm getting errors. I have added `:force => true` which I assume would overwrite the file if it existed. I'm running this script on OSX.

```
FileUtils.mv(var1, var2, {:force => true, :verbose => true})
```

Result:

```
ERROR -- : same file: filename1.txt and Filename1.txt
ERROR -- : ["/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1396:in `fu_each_src_dest'",
"/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1413:in `fu_each_src_dest0'",
"/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1395:in `fu_each_src_dest'", 
"/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:495:in `mv'"
```

So I did some digging and found where this error is being thrown:

```
# File lib/fileutils.rb, line 1512
  def fu_each_src_dest(src, dest)   #:nodoc:
    fu_each_src_dest0(src, dest) do |s, d|
      raise ArgumentError, "same file: #{s} and #{d}" if fu_same?(s, d)
      yield s, d, File.stat(s)
    end
  end
```

Does this line throw the `ArgumentError` when `if fu_same?(s, d)` returns true? Or does this mean the opposite?

**UPDATE**
The problem was the filesystem is NOT case sensitive so it treats both filenames as the "same file". On a side note, OSX filesystem can be set to be case sensitive.

Comment: The box is running: Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]

Comment: You should upgrade your Ruby version.

Comment: Will that fix the problem? This is not an option right now as this is being used in production and it will take time to get approval.

Comment: I doubt upgrading Ruby will fix the problem. Instead, I think suggesting you upgrade is a knee-jerk suggestion and should be considered a red-herring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `FileUtils.mv` with the `:force => true` does seem to do what you expect, however I think you're misreading the error message. It seems to be telling you that `var1 == var2` whereas `var1` should be the existing path, and `var2` should be the (different) destination

Comment: You're right! I am reading into the error too much. The real problem is both the src and dest are the same. I just realized that this function isn't used to actually move the file, but to just to rename it. Thanks for helping me take a step back and look at the bigger picture!

Comment: Solution is to use File.rename(var1, var2) instead.